# Result not Displayed with $Scope

Tags: angularjs

Here is simple HTML with Angular js controller

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        //Applied Controller for interacting with view
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <h3>Adding Simple Controller</h3>
            <ul>
                //Binded with data-ng-repeat
                <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                    {{cust.name +' '+ cust.city}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'John Smith', city: 'Pheonix'},
                {name: 'Alan David', city: 'England'},
                {name: 'John Hello', city: 'Arizona'},
                {name: 'John Fosay', city: 'Lester'}
            ];
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here result is not displayed. Error in debugger `The controller with the name 'SimpleController' is not registered`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: If using angular version greater than 1.2 you can't use global functions as controllers without registering them as part of the module

Comment: You can wrap it by an app within a module and try again.

Comment: i cannot understand .Iam new to this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you need to wrap the entire thing into a module as below

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleMod">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
        //Applied Controller for interacting with view
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <h3>Adding Simple Controller</h3>
        <ul>
            //Binded with data-ng-repeat
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                {{cust.name +' '+ cust.city}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('sampleMod', []);

app.controller('SimpleController',  function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
            {name: 'John Smith', city: 'Pheonix'},
            {name: 'Alan David', city: 'England'},
            {name: 'John Hello', city: 'Arizona'},
            {name: 'John Fosay', city: 'Lester'}
        ];

});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ybc7KWFPO4aNpJ1hI2K2?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

As @charlietfl has already given you the point that you need to register angular module first.

See an updated example here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="SimpleController" >

    <h3>Adding Simple Controller</h3>
    <ul>
        //Binded with data-ng-repeat
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
            {{cust.name +' '+ cust.city}}
        </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>    

    <script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("SimpleController", function($scope) {
     $scope.customers = [
        {name: 'John Smith', city: 'Pheonix'},
        {name: 'Alan David', city: 'England'},
        {name: 'John Hello', city: 'Arizona'},
        {name: 'John Fosay', city: 'Lester'}
    ];
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code registers a controller function named "SimpleController" in the angular module named "myapp".

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind a controller to an angular application as what you did. You need to create an app module and add that you your code. Only inside that app you can specify your controller. I have corrected the code here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="TestApp">
    //Applied Controller for interacting with view
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <h3>Adding Simple Controller</h3>
        <ul>
            //Binded with data-ng-repeat
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                {{cust.name +' '+ cust.city}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("TestApp", []);
        angular.module("TestApp").controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [{ name: 'John Smith', city: 'Pheonix' },
                                { name: 'Alan David', city: 'England' }, 
                                { name: 'John Hello', city: 'Arizona' },
                                { name: 'John Fosay', city: 'Lester' }];
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

As you are using angular version 1.4.8 you can't use global functions as controllers without registering them as part of the module as already suggested by  [**charlietfl**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) to you in the comment.

**working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('SimpleController',function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'John Smith', city: 'Pheonix'},
                {name: 'Alan David', city: 'England'},
                {name: 'John Hello', city: 'Arizona'},
                {name: 'John Fosay', city: 'Lester'}
            ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app= "myApp" ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <h3>Adding Simple Controller</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                    {{cust.name +' '+ cust.city}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        //Applied Controller for interacting with view
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <h3>Adding Simple Controller</h3>
            <ul>
                //Binded with data-ng-repeat
                <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                    {{cust.name +' '+ cust.city}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'John Smith', city: 'Pheonix'},
                {name: 'Alan David', city: 'England'},
                {name: 'John Hello', city: 'Arizona'},
                {name: 'John Fosay', city: 'Lester'}
            ];
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer